# Store class in sqlite database

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to figure out how to store a class object in a SQLite database for a c++ project.

From what I have learned online I will need to store the object in a blob field in a SQLite table. What steps do you need to take to perform this? I believe you have to serialize the object to be inserted in the database.

For example, I am trying to convert a program from using an array to a database, where each array[index] is a class object.

Currently being used:

```
public class Example
{
    private int x;
    Example(int a)
    {
        x=a;
    }
}

main()
{
    Example array[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new Example(i);
    }
}
```

Similar to how I'd like:

```
public class Example
{
    private int x;
    Example(int a)
    {
        x=a;
    }
}
main()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;
    char *sql;
    
    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        sql = "INSERT INTO INFORMATION(ID,DATA) VALUES ('i', Example(i));"
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, notused, notused, notused);
    }


}
```

Is this possible? Or is there something similar to this to store objects in a sqlite database?

Comment: I recommend you store the members of a class as separate columns in the database.  The class can be a row.  Watch out for data members that contain pointers because pointers don't store and retrieve well from databases (such as std::vector or std::string).

Comment: Yes, "serialization" is the correct term. Have you looked at object-relational mapping libraries?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are looking for an ORM (object-relational-mapping) library like e.g. [Hiberlite](https://github.com/paulftw/hiberlite)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into [MondoDB](http://www.mongodb.org):

> A record in MongoDB is a document, which is a data structure composed of field and value pairs. MongoDB documents are similar to JSON objects. The values of fields may include other documents, arrays, and arrays of documents.

Its very fast and highly scalable solutions at this way